# TesseractOCR for capturing To and From Address

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I came across multiple python tutorials to extract email and phone number etc from by using  TesseractOCR. I am looking for some tutorial to detect to and from address on the courier packages. 
As email and phone number has some specific format, we can use regex. But what regex should I use for addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You seem familiar with the part of how to extract the address,
the second and interesting part is how to check your addresses
It's not an easy mission, you can about the regex here:

[Regular-expressions-for-street-addresses](https://smartystreets.com/articles/regular-expressions-for-street-addresses)

here you can find the standarts

[Postal Addressing Standards](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/welcome.htm)

Code example

[Git for validating addresses](https://github.com/topics/address-validation)

And of course my favorite recommendation, Google geo doing a great job in extracting addresses, even gives a number of options.

Example of JSON result for google geo:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4267861,
               "lng" : -122.0806032
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4281350802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0792542197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4254371197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0819521802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJtYuu0V25j4ARwu5e4wwRYgE",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "CWC8+R3 Mountain View, California, United States",
            "global_code" : "849VCWC8+R3"
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```